# iCarousel auto scrolling not appearing smoothly

Tags: icarousel

Auto scrolling appear smooth, when I specify timeInterval for auto scroll 0.0333. But, If I specify timeInterval for auto scroll 5.0 sec, the auto scroll not appear smooth. Is there any animation duration in iCarousel?

Comment: How are you auto-scrolling iCarousel?

Comment: Previously, I used auto-scrolling based on offset because of that, I faced problem. I overcome by instead of using offset, I used scrollToItemAtIndex. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
[_icarousel scrollByNumberOfItems:85 duration:10];//scrolls 85 items in 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to iCarousel.m file and add the following line of code inside the setUp method.

```
- (void)setUp
{ 
   _autoscroll=1;
}
```